# Is there a way to find the native resolution of an LCD monitor (without looking up the specs)?

Tags: windows-xp, resolution, lcd

Is there any way to detect/default to the native resolution for an LCD monitor (on Windows XP)?

(this is an older monitor and I haven't found the documentation on it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually a properly configured graphics card won't allow you (by default, anyway) to set a resolution higher than the maximum for the monitor, assuming that it can detect it.

Otherwise, just keep jacking up the res until you find one (of the appropriate aspect ratio) that doesn't work.  You're unlikely to damage an LCD simply by briefly switching to an out-of-bounds res.

Comment: Duh! I feel like an idiot for not realizing that one. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As long as you have the correct drivers installed, the 'native' resolution of an LCD is the same as its maximum resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try [Speccy](http://www.speccy.com/). This is a great system information tool. I don't know if it tells you also possible resolutions (not installed at work).

Comment: it does not tell you that.